# How do I get the specific Facebook error message instead of a a general fail message

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

A page request to Facebook when failed always throws up a generic error message:

> Exception: The remote server returned an error (400) Bad Request.

However, when I do the same call manually, via the browser I get the specific Facebook error message as below:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#32) Page request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 32,
      "fbtrace_id": "DYEaqjYnHMc"
   }
}
```

How do I get the above instead of the generic message?

I am already using a try--catch block to trap the message but the details above including the actual Facebook error code is missing.

**EDIT**: here is the code sample:

```
public static void MakeFacebookApiCall(string pageUrl)
{
    WebRequest myWebRequest = null;
    WebResponse myWebResponse = null;

    try
    {
        myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(pageUrl);
        myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", wex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your code? Please add the code to the question

Comment: Look at the Body instead of the Return code.

Comment: Added code sample. I have examined the returned exception. Cant find the actual Facebook error message/ code anywhere in it.